# select a single item from json array in reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I'm having following json file,

```
[
    {
        "id" : 7,
        "intro": "intro_7"
       
    },
    {
        "id" : 8,
        "intro": "intro_8"
    }
]
```

Then I'm trying to filter one of object from above json file, Thats I'm trying to this following way.

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import source_data from '../source/data.json';

function CardIntro(props){

    let {selectedItem} = source_data.find(item => item.id == 8);

    return(

            <div> Card Intro  </div>
            <div>{selectedItem.intro}</div>

    )
}

export default CardIntro;
```

I'm getting the following error, what is missing here

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'intro' of undefined

I tried to use **.filter** also not successful

Comment: find return your object i.e `{id:8,intro:"intro_8"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `selectedItem` property in the objects of your array, which is what your code is trying to do with the object [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). You probably don't want the destructuring syntax. Just do:

```
let selectedItem = source_data.find(item => item.id === 8);
```

Note that you should also change the `==` into `===`. More about strict equality comparison, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using_). Also bear in mind that your code will not work if the `find` yields no result. You may want to put up a check against that.